# Sort keys into a map in react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, sorting

I'm having problems when i try to order keys from a state inside mi map function in react..

the original response is:

```
monday : {1200: {…}, 1500: {…}, 1800: {…}, 2000: {…}, 2200: {…}, 0000: {…}, 0100: {…}, 0500: {…}, 0600: {…}, 0900: {…}}
```

and i need to order like this:

```
monday : { 0000:{..} ,0100:{..}, 0500:{..} ,0600:{..} ,0900:{..}, 1200:{..}, 1500:{..}, 1800:{..}, 2000:{..}, 2200:{..} }
```

all this data i already have into this.state.grid, and this object has all the day of the week. so in my render i use the key like an index, but i cant sort into the map.. i try to set a new state only whit the keys and make a map inside my map, but does not work and i don 't want to have seven state only for this.. any suggestion? Thanks!

```
{
  _.map(this.state.grid.monday, (element , hs) => {

  return ( 
      <tr className='grid-info' key={hs}> 
         <td colSpan='2'><p className="hs">{hs} </p></td> 
         <td colSpan='3'><p className="title">{element.program}</p></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee of order of keys of object.

Comment: ... there is. but its complicated.

Comment: Put the keys in an array in the desired order and then iterate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should turn your object into an array, that can then easily be sorted and mapped:

```
 Object.entries(this.state.grid.monday)
   .sort(([a], [b]) => a - b)
   .map(([hs, element]) =>  ( 
     <tr className='grid-info' key={hs}> 
         <td colSpan='2'><p className="hs">{hs} </p></td> 
         <td colSpan='3'><p className="title">{element.program}</p></td>
     </tr>
  ));
```

Comment: thanks @Jonas Wilms I try your code and trow me this erros:` Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {progorig, program, key, hsend, Id, img}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead `... when i map i was using lodash _.map(.....)

Comment: No need to use lodash at all.

Comment: If the keys are all numeric strings, `a - b` should suffice for the return value of `sort()`. If not, then even a return value of `-(a < b) || +(a > b)` would be more efficient. I doubt object keys are ever going to contain accented characters or characters from non-latin alphabets.

Comment: @patrick indeed, I originally had that but someone complained that the answer was "not working" ...

Comment: You were doing something wrong, not sure what. Just use the code in this answer, that should work

Comment: @JonasWilms it works perfectly! thank you very much!!